# Android Recycler View not show keyboard in landscape

Tags: android, mobile, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerview which displays two different types of viewholder, in one type I have an Edit Text field, when the phone is in portrait the keyboard works fine, but when it is in landscape I can't input, when I touch the edit text for input it blinks the keyboard and scrolls to the last position of my list, and at log cat I got "inactive inputConnection" warning. It only happens with phone when I tested it in a tablet it works fine.
Anybody can help me?

View Holder with Edit Text

```
public static class ViewHolderBack extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    private int qtd;
    private Button btnBack;
    private Button btnAddCart;
    private Button btnSubCart;
    private EditText etQuantity;
    private TextView tvSubTotal;
    private TextView tvTest;

    public ViewHolderBack(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        qtd = 1;

        btnBack = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_back_front);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnAddCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_cart);
        btnAddCart.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAddCart.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        btnSubCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sub_cart);
        btnSubCart.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSubCart.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        etQuantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity);

        tvSubTotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtotal);

        tvTest = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_card_back);

        etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(qtd));

        etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) < 2) {
                        btnSubCart.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        btnSubCart.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    qtd = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

                    if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) < 2) {
                        btnSubCart.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        btnSubCart.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    qtd = 0;
                    etQuantity.setText("0");
                }
                tvSubTotal.setText(String.format("Total: R$ %.2f", dataset.get(getPosition()).getPrice() * qtd));
            }
        });

        if (qtd == 1) {
            btnSubCart.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public TextView getTvTest() {
        return this.tvTest;
    }

    public int getQtd() {
        return this.qtd;
    }

    public TextView getTvSubTotal() {
        return tvSubTotal;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_back_front:
                IntesigMobileApplication.SELECTED.delete(getPosition());
                OrderProductCustomAdapter.adapter.notifyItemChanged(getPosition());
                break;

            case R.id.btn_add_cart:
                qtd = Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString());
                qtd++;
                if (qtd > 1) {
                    btnSubCart.setEnabled(true);
                }
                etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(qtd));
                tvSubTotal.setText(String.format("Total: R$ %.2f", dataset.get(getPosition()).getPrice() * qtd));
                hideSoftKeyboard(v);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_sub_cart:
                qtd = Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString());
                qtd--;
                if (qtd == 1) {
                    btnSubCart.setEnabled(false);
                }
                etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(qtd));
                tvSubTotal.setText(String.format("Total: R$ %.2f", dataset.get(getPosition()).getPrice() * qtd));
                hideSoftKeyboard(v);
                break;
        }
    }
```

My adapter
`public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String TAG = "OrderFragment";
private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";
private static final String KEY_SPAN_COUNT = "spanCount";
private static int SPAN_COUNT = 3;

protected enum LayoutManagerType {
    STAGGERED_GRID_MANAGER, LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
}

protected LayoutManagerType lmtCurrentLayoutManagerType;

protected RecyclerView recyclerView;
protected OrderProductCustomAdapter orderProductCustomAdapter;
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvlayoutManager;

protected List<DummyContent.DummyProduct> mDataset;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @return A new instance of fragment OrderFragment.
 */
public static OrderFragment newInstance() {
    OrderFragment fragment = new OrderFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public OrderFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    assert ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null;
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_orders);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initDataset();
}

private void initDataset() {
    this.mDataset = IntesigMobileApplication.PRODUCTS;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rootView.setTag(TAG);

    //Initialize recycler view
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore saved layout manager type.
        lmtCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);

        if (lmtCurrentLayoutManagerType == LayoutManagerType.STAGGERED_GRID_MANAGER)
            SPAN_COUNT = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SPAN_COUNT);
    }

    orderProductCustomAdapter = new OrderProductCustomAdapter(mDataset);

    recyclerView.swapAdapter(orderProductCustomAdapter, false);

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new CardFlipAnimator(this.getContext()));
    recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setSupportsChangeAnimations(true);

    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            SPAN_COUNT = 3;
            setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.STAGGERED_GRID_MANAGER);
        } else {
            SPAN_COUNT = 2;
            setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.STAGGERED_GRID_MANAGER);
        }
    } else {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            SPAN_COUNT = 2;
            setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.STAGGERED_GRID_MANAGER);
        } else {
            setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
        }
    }

    return rootView;
}

public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
    int scrollPosition = 0;
    int[] positions = new int[]{-1, -1, -1};

    switch (layoutManagerType) {
        case STAGGERED_GRID_MANAGER:
            rvlayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(SPAN_COUNT, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            lmtCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.STAGGERED_GRID_MANAGER;
            break;
        case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
        default:
            rvlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            lmtCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
    }

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
        if (((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) ||
            (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)) {
            scrollPosition = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(positions)[0];
        } else {
            scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        }
    }
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvlayoutManager);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
}`
```

Comment: You need to include your code in your question in order for people to know what you've done and where the problem may be.

Comment: @pixelmeow here is the code, can you help me?

Comment: I can't, but seeing the code will help others help you.